# node.js http couldn't receive request from C++ clients via socket

Tags: c++, node.js, sockets

I am trying to send GET request to nodejs server from a C++ client.

nodejs server:

```
const server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    console.log(request.url);
    response.end("received");
})
```

and here is my C++ clients:

```
while(getline(cin, random_input)) {
    int s_len;
    input = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
    s_len = send(sock, input.c_str(), input.size(), 0);

    if( s_len < 0)
    {
        perror("Send failed : ");
        return false;
    }
    cout<<socket_c.receive(1024);
}

string tcp_client::receive(int size=512)
{
    char buffer[size];
    string reply;
    int r_len; // received len

    //Receive a reply from the server
    r_len = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
    if( r_len < 0)
    {
        puts("recv failed");
    }

    if(buffer[r_len-1] == '\n') {
        buffer[r_len-1] = '\0';
    } else {
        buffer[r_len] = '\0';
    }
    reply = buffer;
    return reply;
}
```

so the C++ client can send GET requests each time when it's typing something in the terminal.

It works pretty fine if I type something right after the connection has been established. However, if I wait for 15-30 seconds after establish the connection, then type something on the client program, although the number of byte `s_len` that has been sent is correct, the server could't received anything.

May I know what goes wrong?

Comment: Print out what's inside of your `data` before sending it. Does it contain a valid HTTP request?

Comment: Why `strlen( data.c_str() )`? Why not just `data.size()`? Also, what *is* `data`? Is it related to `command`? And plain `send` versus `socket_c.receive`, what's happening there? And where's your `GET` request? And where do you check for the connection being closed by the peer in your C++ code? It's not odne in the code you show. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @Mateusz It does contains a valid HTTP request.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the question has been updated.

Comment: timeout?
https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/prop_server_timeout.asp

Comment: Why don't you use [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or [nghttp2](https://nghttp2.org/) or [Boost.Beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/beast/doc/html/index.html) instead of implement HTTP with your own ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the value of `keepAliveTimeout` of the node.js server to 0 could solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

A few errors I spotted:

1. `send` return value is not checked correctly. Condition `input.size() == s_len` must be true.
2. `recv` return value is not checked of `EOF`. It treats `r_len` of `0` as valid data instead of disconnect. This may be the reason you do not see server replies: it may have disconnected but you did not notice that.